# rsync uncompressed to single compressed archive

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

## Question

**How can I `rsync` uncompressed (but highly compressible) data to a single compressed archive (`.tar.gz`, `.zip`, etc) without transferring all the data each time?**

### Current

This is what I am using now:

```bash
rsync -a --delete-during "/home/" "/mnt/external-hdd/backups/"
```

On the local side (`/home/`), there will be thousands of small text files that are compressible.
On the "remote" side (`/mnt/external-hdd/backups/`), there will be an exact copy of the local side.

### Wanted

- local side: same as before
- "remote" side: a `homes.tar.gz` that contains all of the data from `/home`, **that can be incrementally updated** like how `rsync` works by default

I will not be independently accessing specific files from `homes.tar.gz`. If an issue occurs, I will restore it to whatever `homes.tar.gz` contains.

This will significantly reduce storage size since data is compressed.

Prefarably, it should not require `tar czf homes.tar.gz backups/; mv homes.tar.gz /mnt/external-hdd/backups/homes.tar.gz`. That is, `tar`ring and *transferring all the data each time*.

Comment: Why rsync? Rsync is not made for working with archives.

Comment: @vidarlo `rsync` is just an example tool. I have mentioned it so it is clear what I want (behavior like `rsync` that can incrementally update the remote, but where the remote stores it as an archive (`.tar.gz` or other compressed format)).

Comment: We don't do product recommendations here, sadly. There's a lot of backup solutions out there that supports both compression and incremental backups.

Comment: I saw [`gzip`'s `--rsyncable` flag](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/gzip1.html) and thought `rsync` itself might be able to handle my use case.

Comment: Do you intend to create a *incremental* archive, that is, one that contains only files that were changed since last backup? For that matter, `tar -g` is your tool of choice, together with some stream compressor. Notice that it will not use rsync's "xdelta" or similar algorithm; if file is eligible, it will be stored as a whole. For the stream compressor seriously consider using `zstd`; it's considerably faster *and* slightly better than ancient `gzip`, and parallelized (there is `pigz`, but that is not very convenient to use with tar)

Answer (score 0):

I would use for gzip compression:

```
tar zcf /mnt/external-hdd/backups/home-$HOSTNAME-$(date +%F_%H%M%S).tar.gz /home
```

If you need better compression, but slower, use `xz`:

```
tar Jcf /mnt/external-hdd/backups/home-$HOSTNAME-$(date +%F_%H%M%S).tar.xz /home
```

You can speed up a bit `xz` if you have multi core CPU:

```
tar cf - /home |xz -T 0 > /mnt/external-hdd/backups/home-$HOSTNAME-$(date +%F_%H%M%S).tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I rsync uncompressed (but highly compressible) data to a single compressed archive_ […]?

You can't: that's not what `rsync` does.

What you can do:

1. Use `rsync` to copy the files (possibly using compression across the link) from the source host to your backup destination target, leaving them uncompressed on the target
2. Use `tar` or `pax` to copy selected files from the source host into a compressed archive, copying that archive to the backup destination target

If you want compressed archives, then a combination of `find` and `pax` (or `find` and GNU `tar`) could let you generate sets of files that have been changed since the last run.

However, neither of these alternative options delivers your requirement, which is an incrementally updated but compressed single archive. Have you considered a commercial product such as "Veeam Agent for Linux Free"?